# Error 223 when opening a file in a OneDrive

Tags: winapi

For my backup tool I tried to load a file in an OneDrive folder (mapped as a Windows drive), but trying to open a file from this drive results in error 223:

```
auto hX = CreateFile(L"O:\\BACKUP\\1.dat", GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
```

results in INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE and `GetLastError()` returns 223:

```
The file size exceeds the limit allowed and cannot be saved.
```

This is an > 1GB file.

Is there a way to get a handle without actually downloading the entire file, but only download on demand?

Comment: No, OneDrive only supports downloading the whole file when it's opened. You can't stream parts of files from the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

> > Is there a way to get a handle without actually downloading the entire file, but only download on demand?

If it means for one file, the answer is no as Jonathan mentioned. However it should work if you want to implement the tools to work with OneDrive Files on-demand.

When you use CreateFile to open a file which is not sync to the computer, it will download the scream from OneDrive automatically. The error about **The file size exceeds the limit allowed and cannot be saved** occurred when there is a setting on your client computer limited the file size when the files downloaded from online. You can refer this settings from link below or test this feature with a small size file which is online view only.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/all/error-0x800700df-the-file-size-exceeds-the-limit/d208bba6-920c-4639-bd45-f345f462934f?auth=1